# How to pass data from Config file to data table in Cucumber automation

Tags: automation, cucumber-java

I have a static data in config.properties file (ex : email and password) and I have used data table in feature file for email and password. I am passing the email and password in the data table.

So I need to use the data from config file instead of directly using in the data table. I have created a propertyreader file and able to use some data from config file like url but unable to use the email and password.

Is there any way that I can use data table + data from config file?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [cucumber extension](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) for [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) which has support properties from configuration as well as external examples.

You can use properties in step cal as well as can have external examples. You also can use properties in `Examples` with BDD2.